# Active Directory - Search in specific OU without sub-OUs

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following Code:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase ‘OU=test,OU=Finance,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM’ -Filter * | ForEach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity ‘myspecialgroup’ -Members $_ }
```

I want it to only seach in that specific "test" OU, without sub-OUs... Is that possible?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx

You need to set the SearchScope to `Base`. With this scope you will only search the base without sub levels. The standard SearchScope is `SubTree` which will search at the base and all sub OUs

Comment: `OneLevel`, not `Base`; `Base` restricts the search to the base object alone. (Source: too many years of dealing with LDAP in various guises. :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction you're describing is the "scope" of the search, which in `Get-ADUser` is controlled by the `SearchScope` option. The default value is `Subtree`, which searches the entire tree starting at the base of the search; what you want is to restrict the search to the immediate children of the base object, which is a `SearchScope` of `OneLevel`:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase ‘OU=test,OU=Finance,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM’ `
 -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * | 
 ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity ‘myspecialgroup’ -Members $_ }
```

There's a third option for `SearchScope`: `Base`, which restricts the "search" to the specific object you specify as the `SearchBase`. In that case the command will return that one object if it matches the criteria, or nothing if it doesn't (or doesn't exist at all).

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I didn't have `Get-ADUser` at my machine to test the parameter :) +1